# logrotate not able to truncate catalina.out - actual answer

Tags: logrotate, tomcat

This is related to [logrotate not able to truncate catalina.out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499053/logrotate-not-able-to-truncate-catalina-out) which is incorrectly closed as a duplicate, even though the duplicate question describes a subtly different issue with a very different solution.

Question (abbreviated to the relevant parts for brevity):

With the following logrotate configuration, why does the log rotate, but catalina.out does not get truncated? (This is different from the behavior in the question linked as a duplicate, where rotating did not happen at all).

```
/log/apache-tomcat/catalina.out{
 copytruncate
 daily
 size 256M
 rotate 8
 missingok
 maxage 7
}
```

logrotate -v verifies that copying the log file, compressing and truncating all are happening.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the catalina.out file is usually not owned by root, but by a user such as tomcat:tomcat.

```
> ls -lah /log/apache-tomcat/catalina.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 105K Nov  4 13:48 catalina.out
```

To solve this issue, you have to add the line "su tomcat tomcat" to the logrotate configuration.

```
/log/apache-tomcat/catalina.out{
 su tomcat tomcat
 copytruncate
 daily
 size 256M
 rotate 8
 missingok
 maxage 7
}
```

As an aside, having both entries daily and size 256M is contradictory. Either rotate every day, or rotate when the log file reaches the specified size, but not both.